# How to concatenate N rows of a column based on a specific column value in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, string-concatenation

| USER ID | string_col |
| --- | --- |
| 100001 | Here |
| 100001 | there |
| 100001 | Apple |
| 200002 | this is |
| 200002 | that is |
| 200002 | Apple |
| 200002 | Cell 4 |

That is my raw table & I want to use the word "Apple" as a trigger word to concatenate everything above that for every userID.

Below table is the output I'm looking for:

| USER ID | string_col | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | Here | *null* |
| 100001 | there | *null* |
| 100001 | Apple | Here There |
| 200002 | this is | *null* |
| 200002 | that is | *null* |
| 200002 | Apple | this is that is |
| 200002 | Cell 4 | *null* |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maintain proper ordering within concatenation - you should have extra column that defines that order - this is usually date or datetime or timestamp or just numeric, etc.

So, below is for BigQuery Standard SQL assuming you do have such a column named for example as `ts`

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp),
  CASE 
    WHEN string_col = 'Apple'
    THEN STRING_AGG(string_col, ' ') OVER win
  END AS Result
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    COUNTIF(string_col = 'Apple') OVER win AS grp
  FROM your_table
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id, grp ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

if applied to sample data as in  your question - output is

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you! I upvoted your answer but since I'm new it won't reflect on your answer apparently.

Comment: If I were to have a filter to concat the string_col, example: (1< ts < ts of apple). How would I add that to the above code?
Expected output for 10001-Apple would be just "There" as compared to the previous answer "Here There"

Comment: see answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76824239/5221944

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be simple. However there is still a need for an "Index" column to help to determine the requirement to "concatenate everything above that for every userID". Try the code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS raw_table
(
    "Idx" integer,
    "USER ID" integer,
    "string_col" varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO raw_table ("Idx", "USER ID", "string_col")
VALUES
  (1, 100001, 'Here'),
  (2, 100001, 'there'),
  (3, 100001, 'Apple'),
  (4, 200002, 'this is'),
  (5, 200002, 'that is'),
  (6, 200002, 'Apple'),
  (7, 200002, 'Cell 4');
  
SELECT
  t1."Idx",
  t1."USER ID",
  t1."string_col",
  (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(t2."string_col", ' ')
    FROM
      raw_table AS t2
    WHERE
      t2."USER ID" = t1."USER ID"
      AND t2."Idx" < t1."Idx"
      AND t1."string_col" = 'Apple'
      AND t2."string_col" != 'Apple'
  ) AS Result
FROM
  raw_table AS t1
```

The output is:
[image]