# How to concatenate N rows of a column based on a specific column value using a condition in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, string-agg

| TimeStamp | USER ID | string_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100001 | Here |
| 2 | 100001 | there |
| 3 | 100001 | Apple |
| 4 | 200002 | this is |
| 5 | 200002 | that is |
| 6 | 200002 | Apple |
| 7 | 200002 | some |
| 8 | 200002 | summer |
| 9 | 200002 | winter |
| 10 | 200002 | Apple |

That is my raw table & I want to use the word "Apple" as a trigger word to concatenate ONLY N (For this example 2) rows above that for every userID.

Below table is the output I'm looking for:

| TimeStamp | USER ID | string_col | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100001 | Here | *null* |
| 2 | 100001 | there | *null* |
| 3 | 100001 | Apple | Here There |
| 4 | 200002 | this is | *null* |
| 5 | 200002 | that is | *null* |
| 6 | 200002 | Apple | this is that is |
| 7 | 200002 | some | *null* |
| 8 | 200002 | summer | *null* |
| 9 | 200002 | winter | *null* |
| 10 | 200002 | Apple | summer winter |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate N rows of a column based on a specific column value in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76823722/how-to-concatenate-n-rows-of-a-column-based-on-a-specific-column-value-in-google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the passion of problem solving and coding, I would like to share this simple solution to see if it helps to answer your question:

```sql
SELECT
  t1."TimeStamp",
  t1."USER ID",
  t1."string_col",
  (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(t2."string_col", ' ')
    FROM
      raw_table AS t2
    WHERE
      t2."USER ID" = t1."USER ID"
      AND t2."TimeStamp" < t1."TimeStamp"
      AND t1."string_col" = 'Apple'
      AND t2."string_col" != 'Apple'
      AND t1."TimeStamp" - t2."TimeStamp" <= 2
  ) AS Result
FROM
  raw_table AS t1
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp),
  CASE 
    WHEN string_col = 'Apple'
    THEN STRING_AGG(string_col, ' ') OVER win
  END AS Result
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    COUNTIF(string_col = 'Apple') OVER win AS grp
  FROM your_table
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id, grp ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: I have edited the question for a scenario where this solution faced a limitation (look at row 11)

Comment: I don't think this is a limitation of any sort. This just does not fall into your specified logic! It is recommended not to change your question after it is already answered! Post new question with your new logic! and someone will hopefully help you

Comment: Thank you, reverted the question to original one where I had not called out a few specifics. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76824493/how-to-concatenate-n-rows-of-a-column-based-on-a-specific-column-value-based-on link to the fresh question.