# How to concatenate N rows of a column based on a specific column value based on a few conditions in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, string-agg

| TimeStamp | USER ID | string_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100001 | Here |
| 2 | 100001 | there |
| 5 | 100001 | Apple |
| 1 | 200002 | this is |
| 2 | 200002 | that is |
| 3 | 200002 | Apple |
| 4 | 200002 | some |
| 5 | 200002 | summer |
| 6 | 200002 | winter |
| 8 | 200002 | Apple |
| 9 | 200002 | Apple |

That is my raw table & I want to use the word "Apple" as a trigger word to concatenate rows with difference in timestamp lesser 4 from the Apple's timestamp for every userID.

Below table is the output I'm looking for:

| TimeStamp | USER ID | string_col | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100001 | Here | *null* |
| 2 | 100001 | there | *null* |
| 5 | 100001 | Apple | there |
| 1 | 200002 | this is | *null* |
| 2 | 200002 | that is | *null* |
| 3 | 200002 | Apple | this is that is |
| 4 | 200002 | some | *null* |
| 5 | 200002 | summer | *null* |
| 6 | 200002 | winter | *null* |
| 8 | 200002 | Apple | summer winter |
| 9 | 200002 | Apple | winter |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```sql
SELECT
  t1."TimeStamp",
  t1."USER ID",
  t1."string_col",
  (
    SELECT
      STRING_AGG(t2."string_col", ' ')
    FROM
      raw_table AS t2
    WHERE
      t2."USER ID" = t1."USER ID"
      AND t2."TimeStamp" < t1."TimeStamp"
      AND t1."string_col" = 'Apple'
      AND t2."string_col" != 'Apple'
      AND t1."TimeStamp" - t2."TimeStamp" < 4
  ) AS Result
FROM
  raw_table AS t1
```

And the output is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE 
    WHEN string_col = 'Apple'
    THEN TRIM(STRING_AGG(IF(string_col != 'Apple', string_col || ' ', ''), '') OVER win)
  END AS Result
FROM your_table
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

with output

[image]